# Generating forces precisely

Tags: forces, weight

When we like to produce known forces, we know that standard weights acting vertically on a object creates a known force. Now, what are the other methods to generate forces with accuracy? It is a 'do it yourself' experiment I would like to do, so any apparatus which uses simple devices like coils, motors, stepper/servo motors, or similar things would be great to try.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I need known forces to calibrate a force sensor

Comment: Why not use a pre-calibrated dynamometer?

Comment: I think your question, as it is presented, is too broad. Can you provide elaboration on the intents of your experiment?

Comment: magnet+electromagnet whose current is controlled by a computer program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A known mass tied to a thread will exert a constant force, proportional to its mass. That's the easiest of all.

A spring under a light load will create a constant force that is proportional to the extension. See [Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law).

A magnet and a piece of magnetic iron (or other magnet) tied to a known distance will do, too. If it is an electro-magnet, the force can be easily controlled by changing the current.

The servomotors I know usually move to a known position, and they do the force needed (up to a limit) to overcome whatever is needed to get to that position. So they will not, in general, produce a constant force.

However, if you attach a servomotor to a spring, you may get a controllable force. The details will depend on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Awesome! servo motor + spring got me a 'aha!' moment :) Thanks.